# Exactness of tensor product with finite dimensional g-module in category $\mathcal O$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

One of the properties of the category $\mathcal{O}$(w.r.t a finite dimensional semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$) is:

If $0\to M_1\to M_2\to M_3\to 0$ is an exact sequence of objects of $\mathcal{O}$ and $L$ is a finite dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$-module,

then $0\to L\otimes M_1\to L\otimes M_2\to L\otimes M_3\to 0$ is also an exact sequence of objects of $\mathcal{O}$.

But in the proof Humphreys' book, it is only proved that $L\otimes M_i$ is an object of $\mathcal{O}$ and I don't see why the exactness should be preserved.

$L$ should be decomposed into a finite direct sum of finite dimensional irreducible $\mathfrak{g}$-modules and each of these is generated by a maximal vector as a $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module. However, this doesn't mean that they are free modules.

Can anyone explain why the exactness is preserved?

Comment: Is it because $L\otimes M$ is a tensor product of vector spaces and vector spaces are free?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I believe you can accept your own answer, so that this question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Like I commented, $L\otimes M$ usually means $L\otimes_k M$ but not $L\otimes_{U(\mathfrak{g})}M$. Then my question is obvious.